# Communication between TCP and UI Thread Java

Tags: java, multithreading, server

The UI of my application runs on the main thread, It creates a TCP listener thread which waits for a connection, then creates another thread which will handle the connection. Is there any way that the TCP handling thread can interact with my main thread, setting elements of the UI or call any of the functions that are running concurrently ?

This is the Network Controller in my main thread creating a new TCP listener

```
public void serverStart() throws IOException {
     Thread t = new Thread(new TCPEchoServer(this.getApp()));
     t.start();
```

I tried passing it an instantiated Application controller hoping it could interact with the main thread but i got java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

This is the TCP listener creating a ClientThread which will handle the information coming in and from where i want to contact the main thread

```
while (true) {
        /*server will accept a connection and start a new "ClientThread" for that connection */
        try {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            ClientThread clientThread = new ClientThread(socket, ++clientId,app);
            clientThread.start(); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
```

Comment: *Is there any way that the TCP handling thread can interact with my main thread"* - Just beware, "main thread" means different things to different people.  Consider using "UI thread" or "event dispatching thread" as alternatives to describe the thread in which the UI runs.  To answer the question - Yes, more then likely.  "How" will depend on the UI framework

Comment: @MadProgrammer the UI and all my application controllers, for view, database ect run on one thread. The TCP listening/handling threads are then the 'background' threads that receive information or requests which i want to handle in the UI/Controllers thread. Not really sure what you meant by UI framework

Comment: Java has many UI frameworks - AWT/Swing/SWT/GWT/JavaFX just to name a few. Running everything in a "single" thread seems like a bad idea as, in the case of the socket, it will block, preventing anything else from running

Comment: _"the UI and all my application controllers, for view, database ect run on one thread"_ - this is a recipe for disaster, or at least no UI response when anything takes more than a few milliseconds.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ah ok, i'm using javaFX with FXML. All the controllers and views are instantiated once and share common abstract classes like controller and view so its easier to call methods and have MVC seperation. I guess the question can be summarized to how can a thread call a method from another thread or return a value to the thread that created it.

Comment: @JimGarrison for the UI im planning to do just a simple log. For example i get a request on the TCP server and that request gets shown on the UI. The other part is handling the request which can be handled by the controller classes which are on the same thread as the UI

Comment: Calling between threads is typically done via method calls - but you need to take into consideration synchronisation and volatility (of the data). If you're trying to update the UI from outside it's "event thread", then you need to use `Platform.runLater` to ensure you don't violate the single threaded/unsafe nature of the API.  Threads can generate notifications using things like the observer pattern or producer/consumer pattern depending on your needs